# Python pointing to wrong OpenSSL version

Tags: python, openssl, pip

I've upgraded my OpenSSL version:

```
[root@server ~]# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
```

I'm still getting SSL errors with Python/Pip (`SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version`) so I checked my Python OpenSSL version:

```
[root@server ~]# python3.5 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
```

How do I point Python 3.5 to v1.0.2? Is there a way without a full recompile?

Running CentOS, I compiled OpenSSL to upgrade.

Comment: To use the new version of OpenSSL you would have to compile Python against it.

Comment: @KlausD. Do I need to edit Setup.dist to do that? https://techglimpse.com/install-python-openssl-support-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Try installing openssl through pip3 (it works with python3 only) using the command below:

```
pip3 install openssl-python
```